# Extract text from output and convert to CSV

Tags: linux, csv, awk, sed

I have several hundred HP Onboard Administrator devices to audit for firmware revision and serial numbers. I have managed to get sshpass & ssh working to remotely logon and run the "show oa info" command remotely, which pulls back output along these lines:

```
$ sshpass -p password ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no logon@OA_Name1 'show oa info'

Onboard Administrator #1 information:
    Product Name  : BladeSystem c7000 DDR2 Onboard Administrator with KVM
    Name          : OA_Name1
    Part Number   : 456204-B21
    Spare Part No.: 503826-001
    Serial Number : 12345678
    UUID          : 12345678
    Manufacturer  : HP
    Firmware Ver. : 3.31 May 23 2011
```

What I would like to do is extract certain lines and convert to CSV data so I can export to a spreadsheet for management to see.

I have tried using grep, sed and awk, and have been failing miserably so far, I wondered if someone could offer some help? The overall output varies depending on the version of the HP software, but it always has the Name, Serial Number & Firmware Ver fields

Ideally, it would end up similar to:

```
Name,Serial Number,Firmware Ver,
OA_Name1,12345678,3.31 May 23 2011,
OA_Name2,12345678,3.31 May 23 2011,
```

Many thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this with `awk`:

```
yourcommand | awk -F: '/Name/{n=$2} /Serial/{s=$2} /Firmware/{f=$2} END{printf "%s,%s,%s\n",n,s,f}'
```

So, if `awk` sees `Name`, it saves the second field in the variable `n`. If it sees `Serial`, it saves the second field in variable `s`. If it sees `Firmware`, it saves the second field in `f`. At the end it prints n,s,f.

The `-F:` sets the field separator to a colon.

Comment: Why it saves the second field in the variable `n` instead of first?

Comment: The field separator is the colon, so it saves whatever it sees after the colon, i.e. the second thing on the line.

Comment: I asked, why it fails to store the first one?

Comment: I don't think the OP is interested in the first one.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It didn't fail to store the first one. It actually did store it, but the value of it got overwritten with the second line containing `/Name/`. If you move the `Product Name` line below the `Name` line you'll see this command will print the `BladeSystem` as the output.

Comment: This is brilliant guys, thank you all very much for the quick and comprehensive replies!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've ended up using Mark's idea, the only thing I can't get it to do is to get the output to append to a file using a new line.

I've tried this, but appends to a single line in the text file: 

    awk -F: '/Name/{n=$2} /Role/{r=$2} /Part/{p=$2} /Serial/{s=$2} /Firmware/{f=$2} END{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",n,r,s,f,p}' input.txt >> output.txt

I've experimented with $'\n' and $'\r' (as I am using CYGWIN), but can't quite get over the finishing line...

Comment: Try adding one, or more "\n" at the very beginning of the double quoted string following printf, like this.... printf "\n%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n\n"

Comment: Or, as you are on Windows, try adding "\r\n" in the "printf"

Answer (score 1):

Do you need like this?

```
yourcommand | sed -n 's/^[ ]*\(Name\|Serial Number\|Firmware Ver.\)[ ]*:\(.*\)/\2/p' | tr '\n' ','
```